# Windows Workflow Assembly '' can not be resolved

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, workflow

I'm working on an older visual studio 2010 project that contains a workflow .asmx file. I've copied the code on to a virtual server and tried to rebuild the project and i get this error:

Assembly '' can not be resolved.  Please add a reference to this assembly in the project that is being built.

I know the code is fine as it still builds as expected on the original laptop just not in the virtual PC. I've even gone so far as to create a blank .asmx file which gives the same error. no assembly is given.

```
<Activity x:Class="Activity1" 
      mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
      xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System"
      xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" 
      xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
      xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml"
      xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" 
      xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System"
      xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
      xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core"
      xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
      xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" 
      xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this was on a virtual machine which had .net 4.0 framework installed. After a lot of searching I found a few comments with patches and updates to the framework which were not always picked up by widows update. Windows would not allow me to install the patches as it was convinced they were already installed.

After no luck with the patches I installed .net 4.5 which has solved the problem.

I leave this here in case anybody else has a similar problem. I also installed the silver light SDK which may also have helped.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework